# Python Keras installation on Windows 10 _gru_ops.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, keras

I have to install Keras with Tensorflow on windows 10. I followed the tutorial on the official website https://keras.io/#installation.

The installation of Tensorflow and Keras seems to work properly but when I import Keras in a python terminal I have this :

```
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .engine import Layer
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .training import Model
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .. import callbacks as cbks
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import crf
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\crf\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.crf.python.ops.crf import _lengths_to_masks
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\crf\python\ops\crf.py", line 44, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import core_rnn_cell
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.gru_ops import *
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\python\ops\gru_ops.py", line 32, in <module>
    resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("_gru_ops.so"))
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\util\loader.py", line 55, in load_op_library
    ret = load_library.load_op_library(path)
  File "C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\load_library.py", line 64, in load_op_library
    None, None, error_msg, error_code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: C:\Users\Clémence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\python\ops\_gru_ops.dll not found
```

It looks like this file is missing : _gru_ops.dll

Thank's for your answers and your help

Comment: Looks like it's a recent bug
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9819

Comment: Can you please put the output of DependencyWalker here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue but couldn't figure out how to solve it properly. While Anaconda environment has almost all needed packages preinstalled and will fix your problem, I would recommend you the following:

- install Anaconda from: https://www.continuum.io/downloads
- start Anacondas Prompt as admin and check with:`pip install keras` and `pip install tensorflow` if needed packages are installed, yet
- now use the new Python interpreter in your IDE or for compiling (in PyCharm for example go to settings --> project interpreter and choose your path)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it seemed that tensorflow wasn't handling very well path with accents (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9481).

I had a "é" in my path to tensorflow (as you do) and moving my installation to another folder fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the XX.dll to XX.dll.bak.Maybe the system asks the trustedinstaller

Answer (score 0):

- uninstall tensorflow use `pip uninstall tensorflow`
- run cmd as admin and then use `pip install tensorflow`